# How to add html custom validation schema in visual studio 2012

Tags: html, validation, visual-studio-2012, intellisense

How can I add a custom HTML validation schema into VS 2012?
The solution for VS 2005/2008 doesn't work anymore since registry key structure has been changed.

Regards, Ronny